# Is there any way to tag more than 50 people in Facebook photo?

Tags: facebook

My dear friend is stuck with a problem. He's tagged his wedding invitation to his friends but he has a lot of friends and those not tagged are upset.

Please tell me is there any way to tag more than 50 Persons on a photo?

Do I have to send request mail to Facebook for above?

Comment: Look at this photo...it has more than 50 friends tagged. How is it possible?
[link text][1]


  [1]: http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=188778631133856

Comment: i have found many pics with around more than 50 tags !!
how did they do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming that your friend has a wedding photo with, say, 100 guests in four rows, then he could post the photo twice and tag the front two rows in one photo and the back two rows in the other photo.

That should avoid any angriness amongst his friends.

Comment: Exactly. Plus one.

Comment: +1 this is a workaround, good one, but still a workaround

Comment: But that is alternative ...

Comment: @WebLover Yes, it is an alternative or workaround and so in that sense doesn’t truly answer your original question. If Facebook has a system limit of 50 tags per photo then the only way of changing that is to appeal directly to Facebook, and hope that they make a system change to increase the limit. In the meantime, if the wedding guests are still angry then you could utilise my workaround.

Comment: that has been done b4 posting... Thanks for suggestion