# How many friends I can tag on my Facebook photo?

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos, facebook-tags

How many friends I can tag on my Facebook photo?

Can I tag all of my 1000 friends on a single photo?

Comment: See - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10191/is-there-any-way-to-tag-more-than-50-people-in-facebook-photo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 800x600px photo would display each of you friends maximal on a average of 480px. For example a area of 20x24px for each friend. I don't think that one could identify all of their 1000 'friends' to tag them. So answer is no!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Facebook Help Article](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=217258071632275), 50 photos.

> You can tag up to 50 people or Pages in a photo. Some tags may not be
>   visible if there are tag requests pending. If you have reached the
>   limit, an existing tag will need to be removed by you or the person
>   who posted the photo before another tag can be added.

Comment: 60 persons in the german translation...