# How to tag more than 20 people in Facebook

Tags: facebook

In [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10191/is-there-any-way-to-tag-more-than-50-people-in-facebook-photo), someone is asking how to tag more than 50 people in a picture. He even has a link to someone who has done it.

I can only tag up to 20 people.

How are some people able to tag more than 20 people?

Comment: Facebook tag limit is 50, so you should be able to tag 50 people: http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=217258071632275

Comment: What about for status updates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can status tag up 10 users.
You can location tag up to 20 users.
You can photo tag up to 50 users.

You are talking about different things.

I assume you are talking about the location tag.

[image: Location]

As always with actions that only one user is able to accomplish but the masses cannot; it's best not to try to attempt it. The correct answer is: it is not possible to tag pass the limit. And if it is possible you put yourself in the "might get blocked/banned from Facebook for crossing some abstract clause in the Facebook TOS" boat.

As for the reasoning for the limits comes down to distribution. You are using a hammer to fry your eggs. In most cases, these actions come from users trying to promote an event, spammers or an irrelevant photo of a cat/cartoon/joke.